# I want to retrieve the status and set to ion-toggle in ionic 4

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4

I have a simple sleep mode ion-toggle in ionic 4. I want to change the checked property on ionViewWillEnter() property so that on loading the page, if I choose toggle sleep "off" then next time I open the app the toggle should show me "off" otherwise "on".

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Sleep Mode</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="sleepmode" checked={{sleepmode}} (ionChange)="mySleep()"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

Here is the status I could change in Firebase on clicking toggle:

```
const sleepRef = firebase.database().ref('sleep');
    sleepRef.update({
      status: this.sleepmode,
});
```

Here is the sample JSON in firebase:

```
sleep
  status: false
```

Answer (score 0):

this link will help you to retrieve data form [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#get_a_database_reference)

you can retrieve data with this command.

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + 
userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
 var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
 // ...
});
```

Comment: I'm not talking about storage. I'm talking about real-time database

Comment: you are using realtime DB or Firebase Cloud?

Comment: this link will help you to retrieve data form Firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: I'm using realtime DB

Comment: Now you can also check my updated and i also add the code. you can also check from documentations.